# Using Arcmap in GIS pro C#

Tags: c#, gis, arcmap

I am doing a Migration from Arcmap to GIS PRO and I am trying to replace arcmap with new interface or corresponding code.

I am new to GIS and GIS pro.
What is the correct way to replace Arcmap in GIS pro

Error:

Error   CS0103  The name 'Arcmap' does not exist in the current context

Here is the Code examples

```
Arcmap.FocusMap.AddLayer((ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.ILayer)ctfl);
Arcmap.ActiveView.Refresh();
```

What I have tried:

IMxDocument document;

```
document.ActiveView.Refresh
IMxDocument mxdoc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
```

but I keep getting the same error cannot find ArcMap.

I tried adding the arcmap and arcmapUI reference

[image]